# Blue/Green deployment for service that using Kafka in docker swarm

Tags: apache-kafka, blue-green-deployment

**Goal:** is to organize blue/green deployment for the particular spring-boot service which is using Kafka.(I'm not interested how to solve B/G on REST or DB layer so lets assume that this part of B/G is already done on LB)

**I want:** to run two instances of service in docker swarm cluster simultaneously. But one of them must be in sleep mode i.e. do not produce and consume any messages.

**Biggest problem:** it is not a big deal to set scale = 2 for my service. However in this case each instance of service will consume events and process them. This leads to disaster. So I need simple and transparent mechanism for turning off all services' producers and consumers and restore them with specific offset

I`m looking for an example or suggestions how to achieve that.

**Current idea:** is to store current offsets in zookeeper and write custom layer that will pool those configs and manage consumers and producers based on that. However, I believe some better and simpler way/framework exists.

Comment: When you say "B/G is already done on LB", than your question makes no sense. You need to deploy your service two times (not scale=2). and you load balancer choose one active (so one you put to sleep with scale=0). that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately  no. I have  to run two instances of service whole the time. Otherwise there will be downtime until new service is up. Or I misunderstand you.

Comment: I guess yes. You need to deploy `--name myservice_blue` and `--name myservice_red`. your load balancer requests only the blue one. the red can be scale=0. When you update your red service, you scale it up to >= 1 and the blue goes scale=0, and you LB requests the red one.

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches:
1. Pause and resume - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#pause-resume

2. For each topic split to 2 topics: active/non-active, and switch between them
3. If you use public cloud - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-kafka-on-aws/

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.